# cross sections using disks or washers method to rotate about the line $y=4$

Tags: calculus

I am dealing with a cross-sections problem that I cannot seem to solve. I have graphed it and gotten this equation for the volume, but it does not seem to lead me to the proper answer. $$ V=\int_0^2\pi(4-x^2)^2\;dx$$

Can I receive confirmation that I have the right formula for solving the volume and that from here, all I have to do it take the integral?

**Problem**: Using disks or washers, find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating
    the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=4$ about the line $y=4$.

Comment: For starters, if you're integrating around the $y$-axis (you have $\int dy$), you can't be integrating a function that is in terms of $x$..

Comment: +1, Better rewrite the integrand as a function in terms of $y$

Comment: If I am integrating about the line $y=4$, doesn't that mean I am revolving around the $x$-axis?

Comment: Then it should be $\int f(x) dx$ not $\int f(x) dy$..

Comment: @Mattos that was a typo sorry, fixed.

Comment: The setup of the integral is right (disk).

Comment: @RyanGray Did you manage to solve the problem? What was your result?

Comment: @Mattos I got $4.27pi$. Is that what you got?

Comment: @RyanGray I got $$\frac{256\pi}{15}$$

Comment: @RyanGray Sounds like you've just done the integration incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, replacing the $dy$ by a $dx$ and integrating your original integral gives the correct answer, namely $256\pi/15$. On the other hand you can use a horizontal cross section in which case you get a "y-integral", that is $\displaystyle \pi\int_0^4 2\sqrt{y} (4-y)\, dy=256\pi/15$ as well.

I can assure you that this number, $\frac{256\pi}{15}$ is the correct answer (verified by Maple as well).

Comment: $(256pi)/15$ is not the correct answer though.

Comment: @RyanGray It is if your volume integral $V$ is correct.

Comment: Well, that's what I am asking. Based off the question, did I set up the integral properly?

Comment: This is about the volume of a solid of revolution, right? If so, then your integral is set up correctly.